# Exporting Data to a Specific Row of a CSV in Python w/ Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv

I'm attempting to build a script to train a NER model in the following format:

| Comment # | Word |
| --- | --- |
| Comment 1 | I |
|  | am |
|  | Bert |
|  | . |
| Comment 2 | What |
|  | time |
| ... | ... |

I've figured out everything else, but I need to print the comment # to the first column of the first empty row. In the case of the table above, it would print "Comment 3" after comment two's sentence has completed in the following row. Any ideas?

I've tried utilizing the counter variable in combination with df.loc[], but unfortunately that doesn't seem to sync up with a CSV export.

Comment: We now know what your expected output is, but what is your input data? Please also share your code attempts and the problem you run into.